# how to send data to a python script and generate a dynamic text and display in powerbi dashboard?

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement where I need to call a python API/script from Power BI each time a filter is applied and need to send data to the API to perform some NLG.

The python API/script will return a sentence or set of sentences which I need to display on the Power BI dashboard.

Is this possible to achieve in Power BI and if yes, how do I proceed with it.

Some additional details:
For eg, if I have created a bar chart for employee details with a filter for salary received during a particular month, as soon as the filter changes, I want to call the API/script and send the data for that particular month and get back the NLG analysis from the API/script.

I want to print something like "Employee E1 has received 1500/- salary during Jan2022". Here E1, 1500 & Jan2022 are dynamic.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

In Power BI you can either use Python to perform ETL (build the datamodel) or to create visuals. Your usecase is visuals: [Create Python visuals in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals) Within the Power BI Desktop you can use any Python package, but if you plan to use your report in the Power BI Service too, there are some harsh restrictions regarding the supported packages: [Create visuals by using Python packages in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-python-packages-support).

However, for something as simple as your sample sentence you don't need Python/NLG.

Comment: I don't want to use smart narrative or powerbi tool but want my python scipt to generate it.Thanks.